# Making text in a text view show dots instead of coliding with another textview(Android)

Tags: android, textview

I have the following problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzbwL.jpg

I have an Android application which uses lists, a custom list item, and some TextViews which are populated with text.

How can i make that text have maximum 3 lines and not overlap the right number(25)?

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewAlertList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ellipse103"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDistanceLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:hint="Distance:"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewAlertList"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewAlertList"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDistanceKmListItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:hint="N/A"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewDistanceLabel"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewAlertList"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewAlertList"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAlertTimeListItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:hint="Test minutes ago"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAlertDescriptionListItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:ellipsize="@+id/textViewAlertBusNumberListItem"
            android:singleLine="false"/>



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_iancu_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAlertBusNumberLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Channel"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAlertBusNumberListItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want it to show some dots if it passes 3 lines.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you use the weight attribute, set the width to 0dp instead to wrap_content. I also prefer using whole numbers (eventhough I don't know if it makes any difference). 
To set the maximum lines just use the maxLines attribute. For the dots use:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this, creating 2 horizontal layouts stacked one above the other, this should work then you'll just have to play with padding.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewAlertList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ellipse103"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewAlertList">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAlertTimeListItem"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Test minutes ago"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAlertBusNumberLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Channel"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_iancu_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewAlertList"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAlertDescriptionListItem"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAlertBusNumberListItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDistanceLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:hint="Distance:"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewAlertList"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewAlertList"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDistanceKmListItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:hint="N/A"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewDistanceLabel"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewAlertList"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```